# on the sum of an infinite series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, exponential-function

Got stuck with this series:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(\theta+2+k)(\theta+1)^{k+1}}
$$
which should be equal to
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\theta+1}}{\theta+1-t}\textrm{d}t
$$
But why? Which is the missing passage?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\theta+2+k}=\int_{0}^{1} t^{\theta+1+k}\,dt, $$ hence to compute your series you just need to integrate the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiation and integration will help, you have to somehow construct a geometric series and choosing a function, that upon differentiation, will eliminate the extra term, you will succeed.

Consider a function
$$f(t)=\frac{t^{\theta+1+k+1}}{(\theta+1+k+1)(\theta+1)^{k+1}}$$
Differentiate
$$f'(t)=\frac{t^{\theta+k+1}}{(\theta+1)^{k+1}}=t^\theta \left(\frac{t}{\theta+1}\right)^{k+1}$$
Sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f'(t)=t^{\theta}\frac{t/(\theta+1)}{1-t/(\theta+1)}=\frac{t^{\theta+1}}{\theta+1-t}$$
Integrate back and take into account that the original sum was $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(1)$.

This is a very general trick regarding the generating functions. All sums that differ from geometric sum by polynomial factors in $k$, can be solved with this method.